# Domain of an Integral

Tags: functions

$$ f(x)=\int^{x^2}_0 e^{\cos(t)}(9-t)dt $$

Im supposed to find the domain of the function. By observation it just seems like all $x$ to me but im not sure.

Answer (score 1):

A continuous function is always integrable on the finite interval $[0,x^2]$, so I'd agree.